# Non-Noetherian (classical) algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, applied-mathematics, nonnoetherian

My starting point for this question is that, in a very classical sense, algebraic geometry is the study of solution spaces of systems of polynomial equations over an algebraically closed field. It is typically assumed that the equations have only finitely many indeterminates. Then, by Hilbert's Basis Theorem, every such system is equivalent to a finite system. Moreover, having only finitely many dimensions is a reasonable assumption for many (real-life) applications.

Now, what about systems in infinitely many indeterminates? Of course, scheme theory gives a set-up that also includes questions of this type. But a lot is only developed for (locally) Noetherian schemes. Furthermore, to sensibly use scheme theory in applications to actual systems of polynomial equations in infinitely many indeterminates, one needs something like Hilbert's Nullstellensatz in this setting. Indeed, [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2031893) by Lang contains a statement in this direction.

I have three specific questions:

1. Are there problems, real-life or inner-mathematical, that make it justifiable to study non-Noetherian algebraic geometry as described above?
2. Has this theory been developed? If yes, what are references?
3. What are important theorems that have been (partly) generalized to this setting? E.g., is there a resolution of singularities for (general) integral schemes over a field of characteristic zero? Etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perfectoid rings are typically not Noetherian, although this is not strictly about “infinitely many indeterminates”

Comment: There are many prior MO questions about removing the Noetherian condition from results in algebraic geometry. See for instance this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=algebraic+geometry+without+noetherian+site%3Amathoverflow.net

Comment: May I ask, why are you asking?

Comment: There are so many problems that can be reduced to algebraic geometry in the very basic sense. My feeling is that there must be also a great bunch of applications of non-Noetherian AG and that references for applicable AG in this setting should exist. But I couldn't find any, so the next natural step seemed to be asking here. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I think there are two different generalisations. One is finite presentation morphisms over a non-noetherian base. In this realm there are lots of results, some of them scattered in the literature but some of them already incorporated in modern manuals. The other is to go beyond finite presentation for which there is no general theory available AFAIK, but in recent times there are some results about ind-schemes especially under specific hypothesis like formal schemes, perfect schemes and so on. Unfortunately, it seems there is no systematic reference for this.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks.
Did I understand correctly that ind-schemes are objects that can be written as the colimit of schemes and that the original motivation to study these was an "infinitesimal" local study of schemes (in analogy to power series rings)?
My question somehow falls under a kind of dual concept, right? The schemes above are (projective) limits of affine integral schemes of finite type over a field.